# Angularjs, send data from div

Tags: angularjs

I have two `p` tags and a list of goods, each good have a button. I want the information (name, price) to be displayed in my `p` tags when I click on the good's button, but only one good at a time. When clicking on another good it should be replaced by the new one.

Maybe someone can help me with that.

Here's my code:

HTML:

```
<p class="name"><span></span> </p>                     
<p class="price"><span></span> </p>

<ul>

    <li ng-repeat="flower in flowers">

        <img class="buk_img" ng-src="{{flower.img}}" alt="{{flower.name}}"/>

        <p ng-bind-html="flower.name" class="cat_name"></p>
        <p class="cat_price">  <span>{{flower.price}}</span> р.</p>
        <a href="" ng-click="send_data_to_form();" class="tobuy" >Заказать</a>

    </li>

</ul>
```

JavaScript:

```
var Flashbuketapp = angular.module('Flashbuketapp',['ngSanitize']); 

Flashbuketapp.controller('FlashbuketListCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.flowers = [
        {'name': 'good_name', 'price': '6490', 'img' : 'http://image_url.png'},
        {'name': 'good_name', 'price': '6490', 'img' : 'http://image_url.png'},
        {'name': 'good_name', 'price': '6490', 'img' : 'http://image_url.png'},
        {'name': 'good_name', 'price': '6490', 'img' : 'http://image_url.png'}
    ];
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you want a "selected flower" in your model, and you want to change the selected flower when clicking on a flower, right?

```
<p class="name"><span>{{ selectedFlower.name }}</span> </p>                     
<p class="price"><span>{{ selectedFlower.price }}</span></p>

...

<a href="" ng-click="selectedFlower = flower" class="tobuy" >Заказать</a>
```

Of course, you could also delegate to a controller function:

```
<a href="" ng-click="selectFlower(flower)" class="tobuy" >Заказать</a>
```

and

```
$scope.selectFlower = function(flower) {
    $scope.selectedFlower = flower;
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That's awesome!